# Let sites know they were visited from WebView inside iOS App

Tags: ios, uiwebview, analytics, referrer

I'm trying to figure out the best way I can inform analytics trackers that the page view is coming from my app, rather than a 'direct visit' (for example).

I have an app that displays a list view of tons of different news stories, and I want to make it so that, when a user taps on one of the stories, and it is displayed in my UIWebView, the website being loaded is somehow informed that the referral came from 'example-iphone-app', or maybe my iPhone app's website?

Is there any way to manipulate the http request to make the iPhone app act as if the link is being opened by a referral link on my website?

I was originally thinking of just adding a query string with a parameter like `?source=myappname`, but realized this is not a reliable (or even useful) way of alerting site owners with Google Analytics, SiteMeter, Urchin, etc. from where the request has come.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Google Analytics then you can set the `utm_source` and `utm_medium` query parameters and they will be displayed as the referral source. `utm_source` is where you would put your `myappname` parameter and `utm_medium` should probably be set to `referral` unless you are charging per click then it is usually set to `cpc`.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding your answer here, but I am interested in having the sites to which my app is directing users seeing the referral to their site as coming from www.example.com...